# How to insert Parent record with same name of child when child record is inserted?

Tags: apex, trigger

I have tried below code but it is not working. Can anyone suggest me how to do this?

```
trigger CreateParent on Child__c (After insert) 
  {
   List<Parent_c> Parentslist  = new List<Parent_c>();
   List<Child__c> childslist = new List<Child__c>();  
for(Child__c  a : trigger.new)
{
   Parent__c Parent = new Parent__c();
   Parent.Name = a.Name; 
   Parentslist.add(Parent); 
}

insert Parents; 

for(Parent__c pr : Parentslist){
   pr.Name = Trigger.new.Name;
   childslist.add(trigger.new);
   }
Update childslist;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a.Parent_c = Parent.id;
```

`Parent.id` is `null` at this point because `Parent` has not been inserted yet.

Your trigger will need to perform `insert Parents` first. Salesforce will populate the `Id` fields on those objects when they're inserted. Then, you can iterate over the lists again, populate the parent Ids on the child lookups, and do `update childslist`.

Comment: I have updated my code David but still not working. Is there any problem with iterate?

Comment: @Frank you shouldn't be performing a query. The Ids you need are populated on the parent sObject instances you already have.

Comment: Hi David i am not sure how to get child records and updates at the end. Can you please check i have updated code again

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the parents beforehand, then link them.

```
trigger createParents on Child__c (before insert) {
  Parent__c[] parents = new Parent__c[0];
  for(Child__c record: Trigger.new) {
    parents.add(new Parent__c(Name=record.Name));
  }
  Insert parents;
  for(Child__c record: Trigger.new) {
    record.Parent__c = parents.remove(0).Id;
  }
}
```

If you need conditional creates, you'd want to use a Map to keep track of which children belong to which parents.

Note that you don't need to update the children again, because we're in a before DML trigger, so any changes are automatically committed.